# Windows 8.1 API to enable\disable all toast notifications

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, toast

Is there a Windows 8.1 API to enable\disable all toast notifications, regardless of app? Ideally they would get queued when I disable them and all pop up when I enable them (this happens to some extent with the notification center in Win 10), but I would like to do a PC wide disable of all toast notifications.

I need to do this from a desktop app (not a "Modern app") and am fine running as admin if needed